# Change an array based on another array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have the following issue: In my app, I receive from the backend an string containing an comma separated list of numbers, which i convert to an array using join(). Then i get from another method an array containing several objects, like in this example:

```
strArray = [1,3]
objArray = [{'id':1,'name':'A'},
            {'id':2,'name':'B'},
            {'id':3,'name':'C'}]
```

I need to create another array based on this two array, expecting the following result:

```
resultArray = [{'id':1,'name':'A','selected': true},
               {'id':2,'name':'B','selected': false},
               {'id':3,'name':'C','selected': true}]
```

I've tried using map and function but without success. I'm quite new in javascript.

Comment: Have you made any attempt? Done any research? Searched thoroughly here on-site?.

Comment: OP says they have tried a map, but not succeeded. Yes they should have shown it, but this is still a valid question

Answer (score 2):

Would this help?

```
objArray.map(obj => {
   obj['selected'] = strArray.indexOf(obj.id) != -1;
   return obj;
});
```

Comment: Note that you're also modifying the original array as you're working with the same objects.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```js
strArray = [1, 3]
objArray = [{
  'id': 1,
  'name': 'A'
}, {
  'id': 2,
  'name': 'B'
}, {
  'id': 3,
  'name': 'C'
}]

var res = objArray.map(x => Object.assign(x, {
  sel: strArray.includes(x.id)
}))

console.log(res)
```

but consider browser support for the proposed methods.

Comment: If you do `Object.assign({}, x, {...` you clone the objects as well, so the originals aren't modified.

Answer (score 0):

With map:

```
objArray.map(function(item){
    return {id: item.id, name: item.name,selected: strArray.indexOf(item.id) > -1};
})
```

Comment: This would fail in the OP example as `strArray.indexOf(1) = 0`

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps. By using simple `.map`

```js
var strArray = [1,3];
var objArray = [{'id':1,'name':'A'},
            {'id':2,'name':'B'},
            {'id':3,'name':'C'}];

var resultArray = objArray.map(function(obj){
  obj.selected = strArray.indexOf(obj.id) > -1;
  return obj;
});

console.log(resultArray);
```